# JQuery Auto Click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem, I have 3 button lets say it's called **#pos1, #pos2 and #pos3**.
I want to makes it **automatically click #pos1 button in 2 seconds, after that click the #pos2 after another 2 seconds, and #pos3 after another 2 seconds,**
after that back to the #pos1 in another 2 seconds and so on via jQuery.

HTML

```
<button id="pos1">Pos1</button> 
<button id="pos2">Pos2</button> 
<button id="pos3">Pos3</button>
```

Anyone can help me please?

Comment: where is your code? What have you already tried?

Comment: Have a tried anything urself?

Comment: jQuery [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)? `$("#pos2").delay(2000).trigger("click");`

Comment: [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) is your friend!

Comment: hmmmmm
let say 
<button id="pos1">Pos1</button>
<button id="pos2">Pos2</button>
<button id="pos3">Pos3</button>

Comment: Could you please post your sample code here?

Comment: If you could update your question with any code you currently have, that would be useful.

Comment: <button id="pos1">Pos1</button> 
<button id="pos2">Pos2</button> 
<button id="pos3">Pos3</button>

Comment: When do you want it to stop? What if user clicks on #pos1 while your click juggling is running?

Comment: I just need to auto change
the next button should be my next number

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$(function() {
    var timeout;
    var count = $('button[id^=pos]').length;
    $('button[id^=pos]').click(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        var id = $this.attr('id');
        var next = parseInt(id.substring(4), 10) + 1;

            if( next >= count ){
                next = 1
            }

        if (timeout) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
        }

        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                    $('#pos' + next).trigger('click');
                }, 2000);
    })
    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        $('#pos1').trigger('click');
    }, 2000);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var posArray = ["#pos1", "#pos2", "#pos3"];
var counter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
   $(posArray[counter]).triggerHandler('click');
   counter = ((counter<2) ? counter+1 : 0);
}, 2000);
```

That should do the trick, though you did not mention when you want it to stop running.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know what you already have but technically it could be done via triggerHandler()

```
var currentPos = 1,
    posCount   = 3; 

autoclick = function() {
    $('#pos'+currentPos).triggerHandler('click');
    currentPos++;
    if(currentPos > posCount) { currentPos = 1; }
};

window.setInterval(autoclick,2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood you question right, you need to perform click in a continuous loop in the order **pos1>pos2>pos3>pos1>pos2** and so on. If this is what you want, you can use jQuery `window.setTimeout` for this. Code will be something like this:

```
window.setTimeout(performClick, 2000);
var nextClick = 1;

function performClick() {
  if(nextClick == 1)
  { 
      $("#pos1").trigger("click");
      nextClick = 2;
  }
  else if(nextClick==2)
  {
      $("#pos2").trigger("click");
      nextClick = 3;
  }
  else if(nextClick == 3)
  {
      $("#pos3").trigger("click");
      nextClick = 1;
  }

  window.setTimeout(performClick, 2000);
}
```

This is quite buggy but will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

using [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/window.setInterval)

> Calls a function or executes a code snippet repeatedly, with a fixed time delay between each call to that function.

```
var tempArray = ["pos1", "pos2", "pos3"]; //create an array to loop through
var arrayCounter = 0;

setInterval(function() {
  $('#' + tempArray[arrayCounter ]).trigger('click');
   arrayCounter = arrayCounter <2 ? arrayCounter +1 : 0;
}, 2000);
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/vK4UY/2/)

check your console for fiddle example